# Grocery Crud - Set the allowed file types in upload field

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

My question is similar to this one http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/169-allowed-types-for-file-upload/

The answer there is no longer updated.

how can I set allowed types for file upload in grocery crud with the version 1.4?
Could the file types be set directly from the function? Something like this one:

```
$crud->set_upload_file_types('jpg','apk');
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your question here. Do not merely link us to an external site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment you can not change it directly from the controller function.
But you can change it from the config file at your application/config/grocery_crud.php

```
$config['grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png|tiff|doc|docx|txt|odt|xls|xlsx|pdf|ppt|pptx|pps|ppsx|mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|mp4|m4v|mov|wmv|flv|avi|mpg|ogv|3gp|3g2|apk';
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (i could easily do what Jawaad said, but i needed to define file types for each field). Here is my solution:

https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/pull/290/files

Sent a pull request to GroceryCrud, if they choose to use it or not is upto them.

Refer to the commit msg for instructions (https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/pull/290)

Comment: Hi Syrys, welcome to Stack Overflow. The policy here is to avoid link-only answers. In other words, you should edit your answer to *include* your solution, rather than link to somewhere where someone can find it. This helps make the site readable, searchable, and sustainable.

Answer (score 2):

i tried another solution and it is working

$crud->set_field_upload("image","assets/uploads/team","jpg|png");

it just to add the allowed file types like in my code separated by '|'

Comment: This is THE SOLUTION, this is how you set file type for EACH file type field, most of us don't have just one file type field (in config, the setting applies or every file type field and we don't want that)

Answer (score 0):

Works 100% in Grocery Crud and Codeigniter version 3 
you'd configure your

in the folder 
**application/config/grocery_crud.php**

```
$config['grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png|tiff|doc|docx|txt|odt|xls|xlsx|pdf|ppt|pptx|pps|ppsx|mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|mp4|m4v|mov|wmv|flv|avi|mpg|ogv|3gp|3g2|apk';
```

With $crud->set_field_upload("image","assets/uploads/team","jpg|png"); you cant overide at all , it picks extension from above grocery_crud.php.

Finally in your controller ,this is my example :

```
 function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->driver('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
        $this->load->model('Generic');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

     //$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|rar|zip';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
}



    public function index() {
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    ...
      //dondt forget to set some configuration of visibily from your crud pages where you   want your Upload Input appears like...
    $crud->fields("file_url" ...
    $crud->add_fields("file_url"..
    $crud->edit_fields("file_url"..
   ....
     $crud->set_field_upload('file_url','assets/uploads/files');
     $output = $crud->render();
    ....
    }
```